# Cucumber test not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am new to testing and I am having tough time to figure out the why my test is not working. Here is my feature file called child_user_selected_categories.feature

```
@no-database-cleaner
Feature: Managing selected_categories
  In order to use portal
  I want to create selected_categories for child user


  Scenario:  Creating a child selected_categories for a child user
    Given the database contains no test data
    And an user and sub user exists
    Given I am on the homepage

    When I attempt to sign in with following user account:
      | email address         | password |
      | abc@company1.com   | password |

    Then I should see "abc@company1.com" message on page
    When I follow "All Child Users"
    And I view "Child Categories" for sub user "xyztest@gmail.com"
    Then I should see "Default Filter Level for User xyztest@gmail.com is"
    When I press "APPLY"
    Then I should see "Custom Filter Created for xyztest@gmail.com"
```

I am using factory_girl to inser record. Here is my step definition file called child_user_selected_categories.rb

```
And /^I view "([^"]*)" for sub user "([^"]*)"$/ do |link, user|
  selector = find('tr', text: user)
  within selector do
    click_link(link)
  end
end

Given(/^an user and sub user exists$/) do
  parent = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "xyztest@gmail.com", parent_id: parent.id, default_filter_level: parent.default_filter_level)
  account = FactoryGirl.create(:account, user_id: parent.id)
  FactoryGirl.create(:filter, user_id: user.id, account_id: account.id)
  FactoryGirl.create(:filter, user_id: parent.id, account_id: account.id)
end
```

Filed called user.rb under features/support has the code to overrite some user fields
require 'factory_girl_rails'

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.email 'recdns@company1.com'
    u.password 'password'
    u.src_ip_addr 'hostname -I'
    u.ar_id true
    u.default_filter_level 'Medium'
    u.src_netmask '255.255.255.0'
  end
end
```

APPLY submit button using jquery post

```
//on sibmit this will create a records for user for selected categories
        $("#selectes_categories").submit(function(){

            // get alll the selected category ids in list box 2
            var options = $("select#lstBox2").children().map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get();

            //var values = $('#categories_ids_').val()
            $('#selected_category_ids').val(options);
            $.post($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(),function(response){
                $("#flash_notice").html(response);
            });
            return false;
        });

<%= form_tag "/levels/create_user_selected_categories", :id=> "selectes_categories" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected_category_ids' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id',@user.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "APPLY",:class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>
```

On submit my code do its job. But When it is not working using cucumber when I say press APPLY. I have wrote test for almost same scenario and they work very well but only difference is here I am using jquery post to go to controller and create records. Here is controller code

```
def create_user_selected_categories
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id] != nil
    if @user != nil
      UserSelectedCategory.where(:user_id => @user.id).destroy_all
      @selected_user_categories = params[:selected_category_ids]
      @selected_user_categories.split(",").each{|catg_id|
        UserSelectedCategory.create(:user_id => @user.id, :category_id => catg_id.to_i)
      }
      @total_category_masks_for_user = Category.sum(:category_mask, :conditions => {:id => @user.user_selected_categories.map{|catg| catg.category_id}})

      @user_filter = Filter.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
      if @user_filter == nil
        Filter.create(:category_mask => @total_category_masks_for_user, :account_id => @user.account.id, :user_id => @user.id)
      else
        @user_filter.category_mask = @total_category_masks_for_user
        @user_filter.save
      end

    end
    render :action => 'create_user_selected_categories', :layout => false
  end
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Capybara with Cucumber, your Javascript will not be executed by default. A very simple solution might be to add the `@javascript` tag to your scenario:

```
@javascript 
Scenario:  Creating a child selected_categories for a child user
...
```

What this will do is run your scenario using the [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) driver, which will actually open a browser window and test your application as a real user might, which will include Javascript execution. It will try to use Firefox by default, so make sure you have that installed.

More: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber

Comment: I added @javascript and now its saying `When I attempt to sign in with following user account:                 # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:65
      | email address       | password |
      | recdns@company1.com | password |
      Unable to find field "email" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)` Here is the user_steps.rb code `Given /^I try to login with email "(.*?)", password "(.*?)"$/ do |email, password|
  login(email, password)
end`  `def login(email, password)
    fill_in('user_email', :with => email)
    fill_in('user_password', :with => password)
    click_button('login')
  end`

Comment: It looks like your test is trying to run the login step, but the browser is not on the correct page. You should be able to watch the browser and see which pages it is navigating to to make sure it is correct.

You can also put `save_and_open_page` at the very end of your `Given I am on the homepage` step and this will open a "snapshot" of what page your test has navigated to.